# Firebase Database cannot access today

Tags: database, firebase

Helo,

I Have problem accessing Firebase Database today. anyone have same problem with me?
I try go to Authentication , or storage no problem . Only database it won't show on dashbord

Comment: There are currently no known disruptions showing on the status dashboard: https://status.firebase.google.com/. If this is just in your database, try in an incognito window and disable all browser plugins. If the problems persists, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Everthing work for me (Cloud firestore and Firebase Database)

Answer (score 0):

May be you have no data there so it is showing the create new database page. Type https://console.firebase.google.com/u/2/project/yourProjectId/database/yourProjectId/data on the search bar, and you will be there. Don't forget to replace yourProjectId with your project ID.